# Como adapto mi layout a todo tipo de pantallas (resoluciones , tamaños,densidades) en android estudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

Construí mi aplicación , pensando en todo pero cuando la ejecute en otros dispositivos móviles de otros tamaños superiores y inferiores al mio , me tope con un monstruo que no me deja en paz , que son las distintas densidades y resoluciones , que los tamaños de las pantallas van de las 3" hasta las 9" , razón por la cual no encuentro hasta ahora la forma correcta de adaptarla a todos esos dispositivos , encontré estas carpetas , no se si deba añadir medidas ahí o que otra cosa hacer , para adaptar mi aplicaciones a diferentes tamaños de pantallas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o deva quisar hacer esto , ayudenme porfavor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existen varias preguntas similares en el sitio. Busca "android densidades layout" y encontraras varios resultados!

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso uso carpetas "values" para soportar diferentes tamaños de pantalla y densidades. Me explico:

- Desarrollo la app en base al tamaño de pantalla y densidad de un único dispositivo móvil. En el fichero "dimens.xml" de la carpeta "value" parametrizo todas los valores de la app (mayormente tamaños de texto, anchuras y alturas de componentes)
- Cuando quiero adaptarlo a diferentes tamaños de pantalal y densidades, empiezo a probar la app con el emulador de Android Studio (AVD, Android Virtual Device), donde tengo configurado varios dispositivos con distintos tamaños de pantalla y densidades (combinando ambos factores).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si la app no queda bien adaptada al dispositivo con el que estoy probando, entonces necesito crear una nueva carpeta tipo "value"

Pero, **¿cómo sabemos que carpeta "values" o con qué nombre debemos crearla para que se adapte al dispositivo con el que estamos probando?** Lo sabremos en función del tamaño de pantalla del dispositivo y de la densidad. Un ejemplo:

- Partimos de que sólo tenemos nuestra carpeta "values" en el proyecto y estamos probando con un nuevo dispositivo, que tiene pantalla **720x1080** y densidad **xhdpi**. Tendremos que crear una carpeta con nombre **values-sw720**, copiar dentro nuestro fichero dimens.xml y adaptar los tamaños para que quede como deseamos en el dispositivo con el que estamos probando.

Si además de tamaño de pantalla, queremos especificar densidad, podemos crear carpetas con nombre tipo **values-sw720-xxhdpi**, por ejemplo.

Adjunto un ejemplo de cómo me quedan las carpetas en un proyecto con esta filosofía:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**IMPORANTE USAR EN DIMENS.XML LAS MEDIAS EN UNIDADES dp PARA TODO MENOS PARA LOS TEXTOS QUE SE DEBEN INDICAR EN UNIDAD sp**

Comment: POR FAVOR AÑADE UNA SOLUCIÓN MAS CLARA Y CON IMÁGENES SI PUDIERAS , LA NECESITO , SABES SOY NUEVO EN ESTO DE RESOLUCIONES DE PANTALLAS , QUE NO TENGO NI IDEA COMO SOLUCIONARLO.

Comment: pueso solucionar el problema de las densidades pero el problema del tamaño del telefono

Comment: con esta solución se tienen en cuenta ambas cosas, tanto tamaño de pantalla como densidad. voy a replantear la solución para que sea más "entendible", dame unos minutos

Comment: Mira puedo usar la formulas respectiva proporcionales para obtener el tamaño de px  a pd , también dos teléfonos del mismo tamaño en pulgadas 5" , pero uno de en hdpi y el otro en xxhdpi  , al colocar sus respectivas medidas en cada uno no encajan

Comment: Ahí lo de he dejado replantedo, dame feedback si te queda alguna duda. Importante usar unidades "dp" en general y "sp" para los tamaños de textos en dimens.xml

Comment: Puedo escalar los dp , pero no entiendo hasy pantallas 4" que con hdpi y pantallas de 3" y 5" que son mdpi , entiende esto porfavor , si coloco dimensiones de mdpi para 3" si se ejecuta en un mdpi de 5" , la proporcion que mantendra sera la de 3" y si la programo en la de 5" se bera muy grande en la de 3" , osea hay pantallas grandes y chicas que son de baja densidad , el tamaño no dice siempre el tipo de densidad que tiene , puede ser pequeña con densidad media como grande con densidad media , entonces ahi biene la gran confucion , al intentar programar elementos mdpi en pantalla de 3" y 5".

Comment: Pero no debes pensar en el tamaño de pantalla en pulgadas, sino en resolución. Fíjate en el ejemplo que ponía de dos teléfonos con pantalla de 720x1080. Si creas una carpeta values que se llame "values-sw720", ambos teléfonos usarán el fichero dimens.xml que contenga. Pero si tienen distinta densidad, sus aspectos serán distintos. Para abarcar distintas densidades a ese tamaño de pantalla, deberás crear carpetas donde se especifique también la densidad: "values-sw720-hdpi", "values-sw720-xhdpi", ...

Comment: podrías describirme todos los ficheros que tengo que crear

Comment: podas porporcionar todos los ficheros que tengo que crear , o apliarme mas la imagen que esta arriba

Comment: No sabría decirte, como he indicado en comentarios anteriores, debes ir probando distintos tamaños de pantallas y densidades, y en función de tus necesidades, ir creando las carpetas "values" necesarias con el nombre de carpeta que se adapte al tamaño de pantalla y/o resolución que necesites adaptar. Dentro de dichas carpetas, tendrás que duplicar el fichero dimens.xml con el que hayas montado la app y adaptarle sus valores a las medidas que veas adecuadas, probando constantemente para ver cómo queda.